# getting data from table where one field is maximum in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

i want to get data from my database where one field is max, at this moment i do this in 2 queries. the thing is i dont want to overload the server so i am looking for a way to make it in 1 query. any suggestions?
as you can see i am looking for entry where the timestamp is max.

```
    $query = "SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS timestamp FROM `data`";
$run_query = mysql_query($query);
$highest = mysql_result($run_query,'0','timestamp');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `data` where `timestamp`='$highest'";
$run_query = mysql_query($query);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative, if you can guarantee that there will never be two records with the same timestamp:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you can have duplicate timestamps, then the other answers with the sub-select are the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will simply work as you desired.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    data
WHERE   timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM data)
```

`Backticks` on this case are optionals. But actually `timestamp` is a reserved keyword but is permitted to be used even without escaping it with backtick.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  * FROM `data` WHERE `timestamp` = (SELECT MAX(`timestamp`) FROM `data`)
```

Comment: hi, if i do it this way will it run 1 query or 2 queries on the server? i am trying to make it as less queries as possible.

Comment: It will run only one query. The subquery is part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to minimize server resources, the difference between one query and two queries is really minor.  The engine needs to do pretty much the same work.  The difference would be the slight overhead of compiling two queries rather than one.

Regardless of the solution, you will minimize server resources by building an index on `data(timestamp)`.

Comment: i hope i understood you right, i got a timestamp fiield in the database in which i keep the timestamp of the entry. is that what you ment?

Comment: @Anton.P . . . Yes.  All the proposed queries will perform better with an index on that field.  From a server-load perspective, this is more important than whether the logic is split into one or two queries (although I think one query is better).